# Liquid - Understanding the use of the 'where'

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to create a navigation menu within shopify, where if a customer has tag 'X' and that tag **IS** a collection, then display the corresponding collection link in the menu. Though I'm not sure I'm understanding the use of the 'where' property properly.

I'm totally fresh to liquid so please excuse any blunders.

According to the doc's, located [here](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/where/). 'Where', creates an array including only the objects with a given property value, or any truthy value by default. So in theory I thought I could use this within my link array.

**Here's the doc's example**

```
All products:
{% for product in products %}
  {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}

{% assign kitchen_products = products | where: "type", "kitchen" %}

Kitchen products:
{% for product in kitchen_products %}
  {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}


Output:
All products:
 - Vacuum
 - Spatula
 - Television
 - Garlic press
    
Kitchen products:
 - Spatula
 - Garlic press
```

**Here's my attempt**

```
<!-- custom collection loop for sidebar navigation -->
{% if customer.tags != blank %}
  {% assign link = linklists.main-collections.links | where: link.title, customer.tags %} // This line in particular...
    {% for link in linklists.main-collections.links %}
        {% assign outer_index = forloop.index %}
        {% if link.links != blank %}
            {% assign has_active_link = false %}
            {% if link.active or link.child_active %}
                {% assign has_active_link = true %}
            {% endif %}
            <li class="site-nav--has-submenu site-nav__item"></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="site-nav__item {{ collection.handle }}-collection {% if link.active %} site-nav--active{% endif %}">
                <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="site-nav__link" {% if link.active %} aria-current="page" {% endif %}>{{ link.title | escape }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<!-- / end custom collection loop for sidebar navigation -->
```

Any guidance on my issue here would greatly appreciated.

Further clarification:

> Customer A has the tags Apple, Pear, Peach
>
> Collections exist for Apple, Pear Peach

Expected Output:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/apple">Apple</a></li>
  <li><a href="/pear">Pear</a></li>
  <li><a href="/peach">Peach</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work that way for 2 reasons.

1. The first part of `where` takes a field property key of `link` object. so instead of `link.title`, it should be `"title"`
2. The second part should be an exact match condition, like "Apple" or "Pear". `customer.tags` is an array, or as Shopify calls it a "drop".

Here, since tags are always unique, we don't need to use `where`

You'll need to loop the tags as well as the links. Try this loop instead

```
{% if customer.tags.size >0  %}
{% for tag in customer.tags %}
{% for link in linklists.main-collections.links %}
{% if link.title == tag %}

... do magic here ...

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for the assist and easy to understand explanation, this is exactly what I was looking for.